# how to get row when change in column data

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.0

I have following table

```
Id  | Status | date
-------------------
1   | Onsite |2007
2   | Onsite |2008
3   | Onsite |2009
4   | Abroad |2010
5   | Abroad |2011
6   | Onsite |2012
7   | Abroad |2013
8   | Abroad |2014
9   | Onsite |2015
```

I want a query in MySQL, which returns a record when status is changed from 'Abroad' to 'Onsite'.
In above case query will return me following rows:

```
6  | Onsite |2012
9  | Onsite |2015
```

Comment: so you're looking to query based on what the status was *before* it became `Onsite`? is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query which works even if ids are not in an sequence:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'table_name' t
WHERE t.status = 'Onsite' and 
       EXISTS(SELECT t1.id 
               FROM 'table_name' t1 
               WHERE t1.status = 'Abroad' and t1.id<t.id
               ORDER BY t1.id DESC 
               LIMIT 1,1);
```

Comment: but what if id is not in sequence  
Id  | Status | date 
------------------- 
1   | Onsite |2007 
2   | Onsite |2008 
3   | Onsite |2009 
4   | Abroad |2010 
5   | Abroad |2011 
6   | Onsite |2012 
7   | Abroad |2013 
8   | Abroad |2014 <br>
19   | Onsite |2015

Comment: but what if id is not in sequence  Id  | Status | date  -------------------  1   | Onsite |2007  2   | Onsite |2008  3   | Onsite |2009  4   | Abroad |2010  5   | Abroad |2011  6   | Onsite |2012  7   | Abroad |2013  8   | Abroad |2014  19  | Onsite|2015

Comment: @user1271131 I edited my answer based on your needs. Now it works even if no sequence of ids (I've tested it).